# After using clearTimeout(tick) my program freeze

Tags: javascript, timer

I have following code:

```
var tick;

/* START - timer */
startclock();

/* CLOCK - stop timer */
function stopclock() {
    alert('stop timer');
    clearTimeout(tick);
}

/* CLOCK - start timer */
function startclock() {
    var ut = new Date();
    var h, m;
    var time = "        ";
    var hour;

    h = ut.getHours();
    m = ut.getMinutes();

    if (m <= 9) m = "0" + m; if (h <= 9) h = "0" + h;
    time += h + ":" + m;
    /* EXPIRE - check */
    var day = moment(expire).diff(new Date(), 'days');
    if (day > 0) { hour = moment(expire).diff(new Date(), 'hours') - (day * 24); } else { hour = moment(expire).diff(new Date(), 'hours'); };
    switch (day) {
        case 3:
        case 2:
        case 1:
            /* MESSAGE - expiration */
            $(".authentication_problem_container").css("display", "block");
            $(".authentication_problem_block").html("Your Account Expire: " + day + " Day(s) " + hour + " Hour(s)");
            tick = setTimeout(startclock, 1000);
            break;
        case 0:
            /* AUTHORISATION - error */
            $("#account").css("display", "none");
            $(".cut_off").css("display", "block");
            $(".cut_off_text").html("Your STB is blocked.<br> Call the provider.");
            window.active = 'authorisation';
            /* CLOCK - stop timer */
            stopclock();
            break;
    }
}

/* REMOTE - control codes */
    $(document).keydown(function(e){
        switch(e.keyCode || e.which){
            case 112:
               alert("RED BUTTON PRESSED!");
               break;
            case 113:
               alert("YELLOW BUTTON PRESSED!");
               break;
            case 114:
               alert("BLUE BUTTON PRESSED!");
               break;
        }
    })
```

I have problem that when i get message 'stop timer' my program is not responding anymore. So i don't have clue where i did it wrong. I read online tutorial of using timers in javascript but this does not work.

So before timer gets cleared when i press yellow button on remote control i got correct alert 'YELLOW BUTTON PRESSED!' after is clearTimeout(tick) function called then none of my buttons works.

Comment: Are you sure that the page becomes unresponsive? Isn't it possible that all the actions are inside the `startclock` function and thus stopping to clock will disable the actions?

Comment: `clearInterval(..)` disables the functionality running because of `setInterval` or `setInterval`.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] in a snippet or fiddle to let us try your code and debug it?

Comment: I updated above code...so my keyup is broken when i call clearInterval()

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `alert(...)` function blocks the rest of code from being executed until you close it. I tested your code and it worked fine for me so it's either the `alert` call that freezes your code or some external factor, like other piece of code you wrote.

Comment: I added updated complete code example above...so if you could please take a look